# How to detect duplicate characters in an Array, and create an argument accordingly?

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I attempting to detect duplicate characters in a string.  More specifically, I am trying to find up to two different duplicates within an Array.  If there is one duplicate, add a sub-string, and if there is another duplicate, add a different sub-string.  Is there any way to do this?

Here is some example code I have so far:

```
var CodeFieldArray = ["Z80.0", "Z80.1", "Z80.0", "Z70.4"]; 

/* We have an array here used to create the final string at the end of the 
code.  It is a dummy array with similar variables in my actual code.  For 
reference sake, there may be only one object in the array, or 7 total, 
depending on the user's input, which is where the duplicate detection should 
come in, in case the user enters in multiples of the same code. */

var i, Index;

for (i = 0, L = 0; i < CodeFieldArray.length; i++) {  
  Index = CodeFieldArray[i].indexOf(CodeFieldArray[i]);
  if(Index > -1) L += 1;
  Extra0 = CodeFieldArray.indexOf("Z80.8");
  Extra1 = CodeFieldArray.indexOf("Z80.9");
  if(L >= 2 && Extra0 == -1) CodeFieldArray.push("Z80.8");
  Extra0 = CodeFieldArray.indexOf("Z80.8");
  if(L >= 4 && Extra0 != -1 && Extra1 == -1) CodeFieldArray.push("Z80.9");
  console.println(Extra0);
}

/*^ we attempted to create arguments where if there are duplicates 
'detected', it will push, "Z80.8" or, "Z80.9" to the end of the Array.  They 
get added, but only when there are enough objects in the Array... it is not 
actually detecting for duplicates within the Array itself^*/

function UniqueCode(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
CodeFieldArray = CodeFieldArray.filter(UniqueCode);
FamilyCodes.value = CodeFieldArray.join(", ");

/* this is where we turn the Array into a string, separated by commas.  The expected output would be "Z80.0, Z80.1, Z70.4, Z80.8"*/
```

I have it to where it will add "Z80.8" or "z80.9" if they are not present, but they are being added, only if there are enough objects in the Array.  My for-loop isn't detecting specifically the duplicates themselves.  If there was a way to detect specifically the duplicates, and create an argument based off of that, then we would be doing grand.  The expected output would be "Z80.0, Z80.1, Z70.4, Z80.8"

Comment: And your expected output is ?

Comment: Are you trying to add `1` to the decimal portion of the input?

Comment: The expected output is a string, where we use "CodefieldArray.join(", ");
The idea is to format the array so that the duplicates are searched for, and the codes "Z80.8" and "Z80.9" are pushed into the array. (If they don't already exist in the Array)   After that, the array is turned into a string.
 The expected output would be "Z80.0, Z80.1, Z70.4, Z80.8"

Comment: @RyanOliver If there are 2 values in the array that are `"Z80.8"` push `"Z80.9"` the array? Note, that the code at the question `.pushes()` values to the same array being iterated within a `for` loop, which changes `CodeFieldArray.length`. Can you include test cases for valid and invalid input and output at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RyanOliver i am quite confused. here are somethings i wanna know what if they ('Z80.8`)are already there than what value should be pushed ? do you want to remove all the duplicates ?

Comment: @RyanOliver You can check for the number of the occurrences of the elements to be matched first, then `.push()` or `.splice()` new elements to the array at specific indexes. Presently it is not clear what the specification and expected output is.

Comment: @Code Maniac After Z80.8 and Z80.9 are pushed into the Array, it won't add any more codes.

Comment: @RyanOliver so if both are already there it won't add any code right ?

Comment: Why is `Extra0` defined globally? Have you taken the time to read the link posted at previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541587/how-to-detect-duplicate-characters-in-an-array-and-create-an-argument-according#comment95884667_54541587?

Comment: @Code Maniac  Correct, if they are already there, or if there are no duplicates, they don't get added

Comment: I have those variables defined locally, I forgot to include them in the question, sorry@guest271314

Comment: Can you create a minimal complete verifiable example at the question, including all relevant code, and the actual current and expected input and output?

Comment: Well, since there are 5 objects in the array within the example above
actual output: "Z80.0, Z80.1, Z70.4, Z80.8, Z80.9"
Expected output: "Z80.8, Z80.1, Z70.4, Z80.8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var CodeFieldArray = ["Z80.0", "Z80.1", "Z80.0", "Z70.4"];
let unique = [...new Set(CodeFieldArray)];
let match = ['Z80.8','Z80.9'];
let numOfDup = CodeFieldArray.length - unique.length;

if(numOfDup){
  match.forEach(e=>{
    if(!unique.includes(e) && numOfDup){
      unique.push(e);
      numOfDup--;
    }
  })
}

console.log(unique.join(','))
```

So the idea is

- Use `Set` to get unique values.
- Now see the difference between length of `original array` and `Set` to get number of duplicates.
- Now will loop through `match array` and each time we push item from `match array` into `unique` we reduce `numOfDup` by so ( to handle case where we have only one duplicate or no duplicate ).
- In the end join by `,`

Comment: How add, the code snippet says it works, but my program is saying that there is a ; missing at the let declarations, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var uniqueArray = function(arrArg) {
  return arrArg.filter(function(elem, pos,arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
  });
};

uniqueArray ( CodeFieldArray  )
```